What does "however" mean in this sentence? Does it mean ''still'' or "moreover"?
I came across this sentence in my mechanics book:

We can resolve the force F into a vertical
component Fy and a horizontal component Fh
However, we can also resolve Fh into two rectangular components Fx and
Fz along the x and z axes, respectively.

This is a screenshot of the desired page:

I have consulted several different dictionaries but I am still not sure about the meaning of the word in this sentence

However is a "linking" adverb. It guides the reader by indicating that the sentence will contrast (in some way) with the previous one.
But it is only a guide, so you can get all the important meaning of the text by simply ignoring it

We can resolve the force F ... ¶ We can also resolve Fh into two rectangular components.

The contrast in this example is weak. In the first sentence you resolve F, and in the second (by contrast) you resolve the component  Fh.  The contrast is "(1) We can resolve once but (2) we can also resolve twice."  A contrast does exist, so "however" is a possible linking adverb.  But I would choose a better one like "moreover".
I don't say that "however" means "moreover", but in this context I think the meaning of "moreover" is more appropriate.

I think the key to however being at least "acceptable" in the cited context is the word also. Without that word to force a contrast against the previously-mentioned resolving of F, it just wouldn't make sense.
